# Is a finally block the correct location to close a database connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is java.sql.Connection thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531073/is-java-sql-connection-thread-safe)

I have gone through some tutorials.
They said to close the database connection through finally block.
But I have a question on my mind:

> Think about a scenario where two threads are actively reading on one
>   connection and one thread finishes his work and closes the
>   connection. So what happens to the other?

Is the second thread able to complete his task?

Please let me know if my question is not valid and please let me know the best solution.

Comment: You should not share a single `java.sql.Connection` between two threads at the same time.

Comment: @erickson that ought to be an answer so it can get upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a `finally` block is the correct way to close a `Connection` and other JDBC resources.

You should avoid sharing such objects between threads; while they are probably thread-safe, they are not intended to be used in this way. One [JDBC specification](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/spec/jdbc-spec.frame9.html) says, "In practice we expect that most of the JDBC objects will only be accessed in a single threaded way."

If you have multiple threads using the same database, create a pool of connections, and allow each thread exclusive access to a `Connection` and its subsidiary resources.