# java.sql.Connection in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is java.sql.Connection thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531073/is-java-sql-connection-thread-safe)

can multiple threads use a same java.sql.Connection to send queries to a database at the same time? all the threads will use the connection at the same time.

if the connection is obtained from a singleton class, will the above case be possible still?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but I would recommend that you implement some connection pooling - c3p0 is quite popular option.

Answer (score 1):

No, `java.sql.Connection` is not thread safe. Imagine one thread issuing a command, while another command executes rollback. The previous command would be rolled back even if it would be perfectly valid. Or one thread executing a command while the other closes the connection.

However! There is no problem in creating multiple connections! SQL servers are designed to handle a large number of asynchronous connections. Instead of reinventing the wheel and synchronizing database access in the application, use the synchronization mechanism in the databse itself.

Comment: Does it matter if they are local connections?

Comment: No it doesn't. It is still not thread safe.