# Java JDBC thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

If I have following sequence in a function

```
void UpdateDatabase(conn) {
    createStatement
    executeStaement
    getResult
}
```

Is this sequence of calls multithreading safe in `Java`

Comment: I think you need to show us some more code snippet, like what parameters are used by `createStatement`, `executeStaement` and `getResult`. How are you calling the `UpdateDatabase` function

Comment: Also it will depend on what database you are using as well. Typically databases will manage concurrent requests. So you wouldn't worry about thread safety at db client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is java.sql.Connection thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531073/is-java-sql-connection-thread-safe)

Comment: Just make sure every thread uses its own Connection.

Answer (score 2):

Asuming your threads don't share any state or otherwise synchronize the shared state correctly the execution is only thread safe when viewing what happens inside of the JVM. More importantly however is if your data can still be corrupted.

Every JDBC connection should only be used by one thread at a time, which you are doing. Database systems however define four isolation levels, defining which state of the data concurrent transactions can see. If your concurrent transactions don't touch the same data your fine. If they do, have a look at the isolation level of your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you change it a little

```
void updateDatabase() {
    getConnection
    createStatement
    executeStaement
    getResult
}
```

it will be definitely thread safe

Comment: Well, the question is "_Is this sequence of calls thread safe_". And not how to make this thread-safe