# How to make each SQL query is a thread?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, multithreading, swing

I'm writing a program in Java GUI. I have a `main JFrame` from which released with SQL queries buttons and also a `JFrame` with `gif`. 
For SQL queries, I've created a class that provides connection to the database and has a method for each type of query. 
The fact is that while doing the query, the new `JFrame` with `gif` freezes. 
I know that is because the query is not a `Thread`. But inherit from `Thread` is not the solution at all.

I want every method of consultation is like a `Thread`. To also be able to launch it from anywhere in the main JFrame JFrame without any freezing.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This should be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531073/is-java-sql-connection-thread-safe

Comment: I understand what the connection pool. But that does not solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
Use SwingWorker 
- DoInBackground () Make check here. 
- Done () Ask here showing a JTable.

Answer (score 1):

Since your application is using swing you should take a look at the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class that is designed just for jobs like that.

While you're about it take your time to study the swing threading model, e.g. starting from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Thanks, I will look: swing threading model and SwingWorker. Let's see if I find solution.