# Should global variables still be volatile if the methods accessing them are synchronized/implementing locks?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I've been trying to learn more about thread safety and have been trying to think of good practices when implementing thread safe code. In the context of token retrieval, I want to keep track of the current time, and the time the token will expire (divided in half, so I will refresh in advance of the token expiring). Here's some pseudo code on the situation I'm thinking about

```
long renewTime = 0; //should this be a volatile long?
Lock lock = new Lock
Service someService = new Service();

public void authenticateWithSomeService() {
    try {
        lock.get()
        //...call to login with someService
        renewTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + someService.getToken.getExpirationTime/2
    catch (Exception e) {
        //log or rethrow
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private void refreshToken() {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() > renewTime) {
        //...call to renew token with someService
        long newTime = someService.getToken.getExpirationTime/2
        renewTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + newTime;
    }
}

public synchronized String getStuff() {
    refreshToken(); //check if token needs to be refreshed
    try {
        //...some HTTP call to get an item with the service
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log or rethrow
    }
}
```

So in a scenario like this, are we guarenteed that `renewTime` will only ever be read/written by one thread at a time since 1. the authentication method employs locks and 2. the `getStuff` method which read and writes `renewTime` is synchronized? Is this threadsafe or does `renewTime` need to be volatile to ensure the threads access the same value?

Comment: i would suggest reading up on semaphores and mutex. here is a good article.. https://www.baeldung.com/java-mutex

you need to have a lock mechanism, to lock data. such as an array of semaphores.  GL.HC;

Comment: No, this isn't thread safe.  You'd have to add `volatile` at least to `renewTime`.  Java requires synchronization on both reads and writes, since you read `renewTime` without any synchronization this isn't safe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Can two threads access the same method safely if the access is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617711/java-can-two-threads-access-the-same-method-safely-if-the-access-is-read-only)

Comment: Longs are also subject to word tearing if run on a 32 bit machine without synchronizing them.  Please read the spec, it'll answer most of your questions.