# Creating & Closing Database Connection in ServletContextListener vs Filter

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am creating a database connection in a web project in Java. However, one thing I got confused of;

1. Which is the best way for creating database connections and closing the connection? Using `Filter` or `ServletContextListener`?
2. Once I perform the database operation in a servlet, how will the JDBC connection close? Do I need to close the connection manually? Where should I close the connection? I do have added `contextDestroyed` method to close the connection, but I think it will only work when the Tomcat Server is stopped.
3. Or, do I need to open and close the connection in `Filter`?

Here are the steps how I am working

1. Create a `DataSource` in the Tomcat Server's `Context.xml` file by using `<resource>` tag
2. Reference the resource in the `web.xml` by using the `<resource-ref>` tag
3. Create the connection in the `contextInitialized` of the `ServletContextListener`
4. Do the database operation in the servlet's `doPost` or `doGet` methods

`contextInitialized` method:

```
    @Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    System.out.println("START CONNECTION");
    try {
        Context contextEnvironment = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) contextEnvironment.lookup("jdbc/lunaruniversity");
        try {
            Connection con = ds.getConnection();
            ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
            context.setAttribute("dbConnection", con);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

servlet's `doGet` method:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("dbConnection");

    String saveStudent = request.getParameter("saveStudent");
    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO STUDENT (FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL, PHONE, STATE, ZIPCODE) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        String fName = request.getParameter("fName");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lName");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String state = request.getParameter("state");
        String zipCode = request.getParameter("zipCode");
        try {
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
            ps.setString(1, fName);
            ps.setString(2, lName);
            ps.setString(3, email);
            ps.setString(4, phone);
            ps.setString(5, state);
            ps.setString(6, zipCode);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`contextDestroyed` method:

```
    @Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    System.out.println("CLOSE CONNECTION");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("dbConnection");
    try {
        if (!ds.getConnection().isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("CONNECTION IS CLOSED");
            ds.getConnection().close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1, 2 and 3: none of the above.

You get a connection from the DataSource when you need to start a transaction. You pass that connection around in all method calls participating in that transaction. Then you commit and close the connection. Use try-with-resources to make sure it's always closed, even in case of an exception:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try (Connection connnection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        // use the connection

        connection.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put the try-with-resources in a `Filter` (#3). That way you can add exception handling code to automatically `rollback()` if exception occurs, and you can perform standard connection setup logic there too, e.g. `setAutoCommit(false)`. Only disadvantage is that connection is taken from pool, even for servlet calls that don't need it. Still, +1 from me.

Comment: Do you have any better links that I can refer to? Thanks !

Comment: @greencheese Links to what? How to use try-with-resources? Did you try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=try-with-resources)?

Comment: I am looking for reference where I can get the connection pool and utilized through the filter, instead all I find is being used from the ServletContextListener. Thanks anyways !

Comment: @greencheese I can't find any examples of using ServletContextListener, and I doubt it was using ServletContextListener to get the `Connection`. Sure you can get the `DataSource` using a ServletContextListener, but not the `Connection`, which should always be managed on a pre-request basis, like shown in this answer. What more do you need, with regards to getting `Connection` from JNDI?

Answer (score 2):

You should never *create* a `Connection` when using a pool. The pool is responsible for the actual creation of connections.

You should never put an open `Connection` in global memory, e.g. `ServletContext`. Connections should never be used concurrently by multiple threads. See "[Is java.sql.Connection thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531073/5221149)".

So, for what you're trying to do, use a [`Filter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html), and store the `Connection` as a Request attribute.

Better yet, use a try-with-resources block in the servlet method, as shown in [answer by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227125/5221149), so you don't takes connections from the pool unless your servlet actually needs it.

Comment: So if I Create a DataSource in the contextInitialized Method, then how can I get the connection in the Filter? Can I put the DataSource in the global Memory i.e. ServletContext and then get the connection in the filter?

Comment: @greencheese Calling `contextEnvironment.lookup()` doesn't *create* a `DataSource`. It retrieves the `DataSource` managed by the pool. And you move *all* the code you have in the `ServletContextListener` to the `Filter`. Said another way, you remove the `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: So, the Conclusion of this discussion is that ServletContextListener is NOT the good place to use/get the connection managed by the pool. Right?

Comment: @greencheese Which part of "You should never put an open Connection in global memory" in my answer is unclear about that?

Answer (score 2):

In a Web app, each http request from a user runs in its own thread (or through a thread pool). Having a global connection object shared by all requests is not a good idea because only one thread at a time will be able to use it and it will become a bottleneck for your app.

The recommended setup is to use a connection pool (e.g. C3P0) that is initialized on server startup (either automatically through config or manually in your ServletContextListener). The connection pool will create and close the connections as needed. When you receive an http request (servlet's doPost or doGet), you then just have to get a connection from the pool and return it to the pool once you're done processing that request.

You can use a ServletFilter to automate that part. In your filter, before the call to `chain.doFilter()`, you get a connection from the pool and store it in a request attribute. After the call to `doFilter()`, you return it to the pool.

Comment: How to get connection from pool and how to return back to pool in servlets?