# spark tasks share sql connection

Tags: apache-spark, connection, prepared-statement, worker

I have a spark job which spins out over 3000 tasks. If each task creates its own database connection, that's a lot of connections, and will not be able to share prepared statement. Does any one know of a way to share connections across spark tasks, let's say just inside each worker node?

Note that this is different from sharing variables using broadcast. A connection created in the master can not be shipped to workers and still work.

Comment: Maybe, please post a language tag.

Comment: I would appreciate a solution for any of the spark languages, scala, python or R

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Probably not.

**Python**, **R**:

Workers use separate processes so sharing is not possible.

**Java, Scala**:

Technically speaking yes. You can define a singleton connection (for example with `object` or `transient lazy` variable), but [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531073/8371915) [skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman):

> you should avoid sharing connections between threads, since the activity on the connection will mean that only one thread will be able to do anything at a time.

Consequence? Underutilized cluster with database dependent stage as a bottleneck.

What about connection pool? Once again technically speaking possible, the same way as a single machine. But to keep expected cluster utilization you need a connection / core, so there is little to gain.