# Cache preparedstatement in a thread safe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, thread-safety, datastax-java-driver

I am caching prepared statement so that I don't have to prepare it again while working with datastax java driver (cassandra).. Below is my code and it works:

```
  private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, PreparedStatement> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public ResultSetFuture send(final String cql, final Object... values) {
    return executeWithSession(new SessionCallable<ResultSetFuture>() {
      @Override
      public ResultSetFuture executeWithSession(Session session) {
        BoundStatement bs = getStatement(cql, values);
        bs.setConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel);
        return session.executeAsync(bs);
      }
    });
  }

  private BoundStatement getStatement(final String cql, final Object... values) {
    Session session = getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = cache.get(cql);
    // no statement cached, create one and cache it now.
    // below line is causing thread safety issue..
    if (ps == null) {
      ps = session.prepare(cql);
      PreparedStatement old = cache.putIfAbsent(cql, ps);
      if (old != null)
        ps = old;
    }
    return ps.bind(values);
  }
```

But problem is `send` method will be called by multiple threads so I suspect my `getStatement` method is not thread safe because of `if (ps == null)` check.. How can I make it thread safe?

I wanted to avoid using `synchronize` keyword so wanted to see if there is any better way. I am working with Java 7 as of now.

Comment: Err, synchronization?

Comment: I wanted to avoid using `synchronize` keyword. Is there any better way?

Comment: A `PreparedStatement` belongs to a `Connection`, and while `Connection` objects are *thread-safe*, they are ***not concurrent***, so you're losing more with the implied synchronization of the `Connection` than you're gaining by caching the `PreparedStatement`. It was a good idea, but you should reject it immediately. --- [Is java.sql.Connection thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531073/5221149)

Comment: If you run the statement a lot, you could cache it for the thread in a `ThreadLocal`, but some JDBC drivers will cache prepared statements for you anyway, so you might just be complicating your code for nothing.

Comment: *FYI:* [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) doesn't have a `bind()` method.

Comment: @Andreas This is datastax java driver code. I am working with cassandra so it’s not jdbc.