# Postgres async queries in Java

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous

We have a use-case where we are having RDS Postgres which we are accessing through Java application. We want to run 2 select queries and don't want to run them sequentially to save the latency. If query1 responses are non-null and non-empty then we'll consider its responses for further processing otherwise will use responses of query2.

I haven't found proper resource which mentions how to do that ? I have confusions like whether its possible or not ? Do I need to create 2 different sessions first and then start async call, as I think 2 queries cannot run together in one postgres session.

Please guide me out here.

Comment: Please start here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1531103/13808319

Comment: Just run two threads with one query per thread. Or... you can just use an Executor with a fixed or dynamic pool size.